# Using boost::format print only 2 digits after decimal

Tags: c++, boost

I am using boost::format to print only 2 digits after decimal point for a float value and that too after rounding up. It's like this

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

somefunc()
{
   format outFileFormatter("%1$.2f");
   cout << outFileFormatter % val;
}
```

It is working correctly for floating point values but for whole numbers also it's printing 0 after decimal point like 100 is 100.00 .
Is there anyway to remove this extra 00 after decimal point.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Remember as far as `val` is of type `double` or `float`, even if you assigned `val = 45`, you still have a floating point number, not a "whole number"

Answer (score 1):

You could try [`modf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/modf/) and check the fractional part for 0.00 and then use another formater. But beware, it's difficult to check for an exact value with floating point values.

```
somefunc()
{
  double intPart(0.0);      
  double fracturedPart(modf(val, &intPart));

  if (fracturedPart == 0.0)
  {
    // zero formater
  }
  else
  {
    // decimal formater
  }
}
```